# Why Nanatsu no Taizai anime story goes so fast?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

As far as I understand, the first 2 seasons of Nanatsu no Taizai, of 24 episodes each, covered almost 200 chapters of the manga. This is very different to other series like My Hero Academia for example, where IIRC, each season of the anime covered like 40 chapters of the manga. Why Nanatsu no Taizai anime story goes so fast?